# SSrs Passing Integer parameters to another report via URL

Tags: reporting-services, parameter-passing

I'm using SSRS and I'm trying to pass two integer values (Order and Line) from my first report to parameters (Order and Line) in a second report that opens in a new window.

If I cast Order and Line as varchar in my query the following code will work well, but with order and line as integer I had no luck.
it is not even identified as link (The mouse thing wont change to hand icon).

Any help is appreciated on how I can pass integer parameter to another report in SSrs

```
 ="javascript:void(window.open('http://reports.bis.iss.com/directory/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2fOrder&rs:Command=Render&Order="+Fields!Order.Value+"&Line="+Fields!Line.Value+"'))"
```

Comment: Does it work any better if you use an **&** instead of the **+** to concatenate the string? 

 ="javascript:void(window.open('http://reports.bis.inuktun.com/directory/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2fOrder&rs:Command=Render&Order=" & Fields!Order.Value & "&Line=" & Fields!Line.Value+"'))"

  What does the link look like when it is rendered?

Comment: No, it even throw error

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the set up to test this right now but did you try converting those values

```
="javascript:void(window.open('http://reports.bis.iss.com/directory/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2fOrder&rs:Command=Render&Order="+CInt(Fields!Order.Value)+"&Line="+CInt(Fields!Line.Value)+"'))"
```

Comment: Actually the link is not working when order and line are integers, how ever i tried to convert then to char by CString and that works. thanks for bringing that to my mind that I can do the conversion in the SSRS itself and I dont have  to do it on SQL on my dataset. that keep the query in the sataset clean. How ever I am still curious to know is it possible at all to pass an integer parameter via URL or I always have to do the conversion.

Comment: @FatemehShakhsesalim - have you tried displaying the link as text to see what it looks like? I'm wondering if the implicit conversion from INT to text was adding a leading space and breaking the link.

Comment: Could you guide me how I can display the link as text